# writing bash like script in fortran

Tags: fortran, fortran90

We can write simple bash script to easy our tasks in many ways. For example as the bash scritp below.

```
#!/bin/bash

name="Vijay"

echo "My name is $name."
echo "$name does no like to play football"

exit $?
```

Can one achieve the same thing in Fortran? I tried the code as blow:

```
program simple
implicit none

character(len=1024),parameter :: name="Vijay"

write (name,"(A5)")  
print*, "My name is trim(name)" 
print*, "trim(name) does no like to play football"
end
```

But, I get error message as blow:

```
Error: UNIT specification at (1) must be an INTEGER expression or a CHARACTER variable
```

Appreciate any help to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a very basic question. I suggest reading an article about Fortran, such as http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fortran_95_language_features, and looking at code examples.

One hint:

```
write (name,"(A5)")
```

-->

```
write (*, '(A)' )  name
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the response from M. S. B., the line:

```
print*, "My name is trim(name)"
```

will print out `My name is trim(name)` because Fortran does not do variable substitution in strings like bash does.  What you want is:

```
print*, "My name is "//trim(name)
```

The `//` operator is for string concatenation in Fortran.